# echarts - Ability to add texture stripes on map

Tags: javascript, echarts

I generate a map with echarts.

I'm able to pickup 0 values to colorize them in gray using `visualMap` property combined with `inRange` `min`, `max`, `outOfRange` options.

The wanted result is almost there (see the screenshots) !

But I'd like to display elements with 0 values with stripes / pattern - now in gray on the screenshot. How can I achieve this with echarts ?

Example of wanted pattern :
[image: pattern]

[image: map-sample]

I had a look on following documentation - and tried some code with no success :

- https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#visualMap
- https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#aria.decal
- https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-pattern

My visualMap configuration part is as follow :

```js
    visualMap : {
                type: 'continuous', 
                left : 'right',
                top : 'center',
                min : 469,
                max : 144464,
                inRange : {
                    color : colors
                },
                outOfRange: {
                    color:'#f4f4f4'
                },
                text : [ 'Haute', 'Faible' ],
                calculable : true
            },
```

Additional need : I'd also be happy to be able to see `outOfRange` in legend.

(also reported here : https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/14874)

Comment: Can you please add a [mcve]? - use the edit feature of echarts - [this is an example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-polar-stack-radial) and click on the "Decal Pattern" button and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually version 5.0+ of echart implement `decal` feature.

> We borrowed the concept of decal from computer graphics to avoid confusing with pattern, which ECharts already used. The difference between a decal and a pattern in ECharts is that, a decal is a parametric configuration that generates repeating images while a pattern takes an image to repeat.

More information and samples regarding this new feature on following links :

- https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/13263
- https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=doc-example/aria-decal
- https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.itemStyle.decal

Because `decal` feature does not rely on image there is no pixel effect, unlike using `pattern` !

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a pattern fill you need to use a canvas object as a color source. Here is a code example I use to create dynamic, two-colored, striped patterns:

```
function DashedPattern(color1, color2, canvasId) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.id = canvasId;
    c.width = 120;
    c.height = 120;
    c.style.border = "0px none";
    c.hidden = "true";
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(c);
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = color1;
    ctx.fillStyle = color2;
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    var patternSpread = 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (i = 1; i <= c.width / patternSpread; i++) {
        ctx.moveTo(i * patternSpread, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(0, i * patternSpread);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < c.height / patternSpread; i++) {
        ctx.moveTo(c.width, i * patternSpread);
        ctx.lineTo(i * patternSpread, c.height);
    }
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.stroke();
    return c;
 }

 var c = DashedPattern(p.itemStyle.areaColor, p.itemStyle.secondColor, patternId);
 var newColor = { image: c, repeat: 'repeat' };
 p.itemStyle.areaColor = newColor;
```

Of course, if you only use pre-defined static patterns you can just create pattern images and load them into canvas instead of dynamic generation.
The drawback of patterns in *echarts* is that they are bitmaps and don't look as nice as the rest of the map.
Here is the example of the map I have using patterns:

[image: Example of strip patterns]

As you can see the stripes align nicely between areas but when zoomed in the bitmap edginess is clearly visible. Probably this can be reduced by playing with pattern size.